# jQuery: Getting value from input array

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have the following form:

```
<form>
...
      <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" class="datagrid_ppal">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">Area 1 <input name="config_line" type="hidden" value="0,5,50" /></th>
            <td class="gantt"> </td>
            <td class="gantt"> </td>
            <td class="gantt"> </td>
            ...
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table width="100%" cellspacing="0" class="datagrid_ppal">
...
<form>
```

What we need is to get the first, second or third from the hidden input value. We have tried this and didn't work:

```
        var value = $('th').children('input:hidden').val();
```

Can anyone help us? We would really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you saying that you can't get the value at all? `$('th')` is selecting *all* the `th` elements on the page. Are there others?  `.val()` will return the value of the *first* `th` it finds on the page.

Comment: (I meant the say *the value of the <input> in the first th* .)

Comment: They will be several .val() in the same page. I'm trying to build some sort of Gantt chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of your hidden field is not an array, but just the string: "0,5,50".

To retrieve that value using jQuery use:

```
$('input[name=config_line]').val()
```

To split that string into an array use the split() method.

Combined:

```
var firstValue = $('input[name=config_line]').val().split(",")[0]; // etc...
```

Comment: sorry, didn't see that. you can also use $('input[name=config_line]') as selector

Comment: Please change your answer, #config_line can be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = $('input[name=config_line]').val();
var valueArry = value.split(',');
var v1 = valueArry[0];
var v2 = valueArry[1];
var v3 = valueArry[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll find details [Here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) .

```
var value = $('th').children("input[type='hidden']").val();
```

should work.